# Return Sum excluding K and following number in list using Recursion

Tags: python, list, recursion, list-comprehension

My code is supposed to receive an integer and a list of integers.  It returns
    the sum of the integers in the list EXCEPT, it ignores the
    unlucky number and the number immediately following the
    unlucky number. Im only trying to use recursion (NO ITERATION). So far my code works for the first 5 cases but has issues with the last 2 because they have unlucky numbers at the end. I ma not trying to completely rewrite my function only find the error in what i currently have.

```
def unlucky(unlucky_num, a_list):
    """
    >>> unlucky(13,[1])
    1
    >>> unlucky(13,[1,2,3,4,5,6])
    21
    >>> unlucky(13,[13,1,2,3])
    5
    >>> unlucky(13,[1,13,2,3])
    4
    >>> unlucky(13,[13, 0])
    0
    >>> unlucky(13,[13,1,2,13,2,1,13]) #13,1,13,2,13 ignored
    3
    >>> unlucky(7,[7,4,5,7,5,4,7]) #7,4,7,5,7 ignored (7 is unlucky)
    9
    """

    if a_list == []:
        return 0
    if a_list[0] == unlucky_num:
        if len(a_list) > 1:
            return unlucky(unlucky_num, a_list[2:])
        return unlucky(unlucky_num, a_list)
    return a_list[0] + unlucky(unlucky_num, a_list[1:])
```

for the last two cases I am getting the following errors (filename redacted):

```
Error
**********************************************************************
File "------", line 39, in sum_unlucky
Failed example:
    sum_unlucky(13,[13,1,2,13,2,1,13]) #13,1,13,2,13 ignored
Exception raised:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "-------", line 138, in __run
        exec(compile(example.source, filename, "single",
      File "<doctest sum_unlucky[5]>", line 1, in <module>
        sum_unlucky(13,[13,1,2,13,2,1,13]) #13,1,13,2,13 ignored
      File "-------", line 50, in sum_unlucky
        return sum_unlucky(unlucky_num, a_list[2:])
      File "---------", line 52, in sum_unlucky
        return a_list[0] + sum_unlucky(unlucky_num, a_list[1:])
      File "--------", line 50, in sum_unlucky
        return sum_unlucky(unlucky_num, a_list[2:])
      File "--------", line 52, in sum_unlucky
        return a_list[0] + sum_unlucky(unlucky_num, a_list[1:])
      File "-------", line 51, in sum_unlucky
        return sum_unlucky(unlucky_num, a_list)
      File "------", line 51, in sum_unlucky
        return sum_unlucky(unlucky_num, a_list)
      File "------", line 51, in sum_unlucky
        return sum_unlucky(unlucky_num, a_list)
      [Previous line repeated 986 more times]
      File "----", line 45, in sum_unlucky
        if a_list == []: 
    RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

Comment: What results are you getting? It's helpful to put that in the question so we can see the problem more easily.

Comment: i apologize if it was not clear. I was using the doctest highlighted in red to demonstrate example outputs. but will include the errors.

Comment: No problem, it just helps to have all the info up front. It's clear what you're expecting, but helps to show what results you're actually getting.

Comment: You are not providing an else to `if a_list[0] == unlucky_num` so when the last number in the list is the unlucky number it never stops. It keeps returning `return a_list[0] + unlucky(unlucky_num, a_list[1:])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to exclude the unlucky number if `len(a_list) == 1`. Use `a_list[1:]`.

```
def unlucky(unlucky_num, a_list):
    if a_list == []:
        return 0

    if a_list[0] == unlucky_num:
        if len(a_list) > 1:
            return unlucky(unlucky_num, a_list[2:])
        return unlucky(unlucky_num, a_list[1:])  # <- Here
    return a_list[0] + unlucky(unlucky_num, a_list[1:])
```

But in that case since `a_list[1:] == []`, you can skip the recursive call and just `return 0`. You could simplify that too:

```
def unlucky(unlucky_num, a_list):
    if a_list in ([], [unlucky_num]):
        return 0
    elif a_list[0] == unlucky_num:
        return unlucky(unlucky_num, a_list[2:])
    return a_list[0] + unlucky(unlucky_num, a_list[1:])
```

Comment: Check out [Mark Meyer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61431198/4518341)! It's clearer than mine!

Answer (score 1):

You really only need two tests, which will make it easier to avoid bugs.  A test for the base case, which is an empty array and a test for the unlucky number. You don't need to test for the length after the base case because you can pass an empty array back. With that the function can be written in a way that it mirrors the requirements in very readable way:

```
def unlucky(unlucky_num, a_list):
    if not a_list:                             # base case
        return 0 

    head, *rest = a_list                       # rest will be [] when len(a_list) == 1

    if head == unlucky_num:
        return unlucky(unlucky_num, rest[1:])
    return head + unlucky(unlucky_num,rest)

unlucky(7,[7,4,5,7,5,4,7])
# 9
```

Answer (score 0):

As Mark Meyer said, it never reaches `a_list == []`.  Try:

```py
def unlucky(unlucky_num, a_list):
    if len(a_list) == 1:
        if a_list[0] == unlucky_num:
            return 0
        else:
            return a_list[0]
    if a_list[0] == unlucky_num:
        if len(a_list) > 1:
            return unlucky(unlucky_num, a_list[2:])
        return unlucky(unlucky_num, a_list)
    return a_list[0] + unlucky(unlucky_num, a_list[1:])
```

Comment: this seems to work however it creates another error the the case  ```>>> unlucky(13,[13, 0])```